# SQL: Display the table and its job by yes and no

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

**User Table**

```
Id | Username |
---------------
1  | jdoe     |
```

**Job Table**

```
Id | Job       |
----------------
1  | Waiter    |
2  | Office    |
3  | Freelance |
```

**User Job Table**

```
Id |UserId | JobId |
--------------------
1  | 1     | 2     |
2  | 1     | 3     |
```

How to select this table and display it to look like this below:

```
Id | Username | Waiter| Office | Freelance|
-------------------------------------------
1  | jdoe     | No    | Yes    | Yes      |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty standard pivot query question, with an additional slight twist.  In case a given user does not have a certain type of job assigned, you want to display `'No'`.  One way to do this is to make use of `COALESCE` and replace `NULL` job aggregates.

```
SELECT u.Id,
       u.Username,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN j.Job = 'Waiter'    THEN 'Yes' END), 'No') AS Waiter,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN j.Job = 'Office'    THEN 'Yes' END), 'No') AS Office,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN j.Job = 'Freelance' THEN 'Yes' END), 'No') AS Freelance
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN User_Job uj
    ON u.Id = uj.UserId
LEFT JOIN Job j
    ON uj.JobId = j.Id
GROUP BY u.Id,
         u.Username
```

Comment: I tried your Code bro but it gives me an error "Incorrect syntax near ')'. ".

Comment: @saibharath Sorry, I had a small typo in there, `END` was missing from the `CASE` statements, please try again.

Comment: Now it shows "Column 'User.UserName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @saibharath Use `GROUP BY` with both id and username.

Comment: What happens if a job is added to table Job ? Will this still work ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, work perfectly. Just need to change a bit based on what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT u.username,job,CASE WHEN uj.jobid IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'yes' END AS jobid
FROM USER u INNER JOIN UserJob uj on u.id = uj.Userid
             RIGHT JOIN Job j on j.id = uj.jobid
)

SELECT username,ISNULL(waiter,'no') waiter,
                ISNULL(Office,'no') Office,
                ISNULL(Freelance,'no') Freelance
FROM cte
PIVOT
(
  MAX(jobid) FOR job IN (Waiter, Office,Freelance)
) piv
WHERE username IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@Listcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'Isnull('+QUOTENAME(t.Job) +',''No'') as ' + t.Job
                    from Job t
                    order by Job desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
select @Listcols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.Job) 
                    from Job t
                    order by Job desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT Id, Username,' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select      D1.Id, D1.Username,
                            COALESCE(CASE WHEN isnull(D2.UserId,0) > 0  THEN ''Yes''
                                        Else ''No''
                                        End, ''No'') as UserId,
                            D3.Job
                from        [User] D1
                Inner Join  User_Job D2
                    On      D1.Id = D2.UserId
                Inner Join  Job D3
                    On      D2.JobId = D3.Id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(UserId)
                for Job in (' + @Listcols + N')
            ) p '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the job items are come from a result.

```
    CREATE TABLE #T1(id INT ,Username VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO #T1 SELECT 1,'jdoe'

    CREATE TABLE #T2(id INT ,Job VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(1,'Waiter'),(2,'Office'),(3,'Freelance')

    CREATE TABLE #T3(id INT ,UserId INT ,JobId INT )
    INSERT INTO #T3 VALUES(1,1,2),(2,1,3)

    DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(max),@sql NVARCHAR(max)
    SELECT  @col=ISNULL(@col+',[','[')+Job+']' FROM #t2
    PRINT @col
    SET @sql='
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT uj.Job,uj.Username,CASE WHEN t3.UserId IS NULL THEN ''No'' ELSE ''Yes'' END AS f  FROM (
           SELECT t2.id AS JobId, t2.Job,t1.id AS UserId, t1.Username
            FROM #T1 AS t1,#t2 AS t2
        ) uj LEFT JOIN  #T3 AS t3 ON  t3.JobId = uj.JobId AND t3.UserId = uj.UserId

    ) AS t PIVOT(MAX(f) FOR job IN ('+@col+')) p'
    EXEC(@sql)
```